# Deserialization of json to Jackson Object works but not when used with Jersey

Tags: json, jersey, jackson

I have my Jackson object:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) 
public class User {
    @Id @ObjectId
    private String _id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Address address;
   //getters / Setters
}
```

When i run my unit test to convert a json String to Jackson object with default ObjectMapper, i can see that the Address is correctly converted ! => the test pass

```
@Test
public void UserWithAddressShouldGiveValidJSONObject () throws Exception {

    //Given
    String userJSON = "{\"firstName\":\"Michel\",\"lastName\":\"Thom\",\"address\":{\"no\":\"12\",\"street\":\"example street\",\"postalCode\":\"555\",\"city\":\"New York\"}}";

    //When
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    User user = mapper.readValue(userJSON, User.class);

    //Then
    assertEquals("Michel", user.getFirstName());
    assertEquals("Thom", user.getLastName());
    assertEquals("New York", user.getAddress().getCity());
}
```

But when i get the **same json in Jersey, the Address object is empty !**

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/json")
public Response saveUser(User user) throws Exception {
user.toString();
}
```

Json received by Jersey:

```
{ "firstName" : "Michel", "lastName" : "Thom", "address" : {  }}
```

What i'm missing ?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this declaration in your web.xml file?

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

I am using this in my Jersey project and have not experienced your issue. I read that it helps with parsing Objects from JSONs with nested JSONS (and back).

Hope this helps.